# Packages are not installed. 0 installed, 15 not upgraded

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04

I have this problem where not everything updates, I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but it doesn't work. I also tried `sudo apt full-upgrade` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` but nothing seems to work. I know that typing them out by name works, by name I mean `sudo apt upgrade {package name}`, but that seems like a lot of time wasted, and there must be a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post output of these commands to the question. What do you mean by "typing them out by name work"?

Comment: The output for those commands is in a different language, it just proceeds normally and updates everything except those packages. It says (translated) 0 updated, 0 new installed, 0 removed, 15 not installed

Comment: You can run `LANG=C sudo apt update` to get output in Engish.

Comment: The solution is to wait till phased upgrades are ready to install.